# Using HashMap in dropdown list in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In my controller I am setting a hashmap

```
@ModelAttribute("clientImpMap")
public Map<String,String> populateClientImpMap() throws MalformedURLException, IOException 
{

    Map<String,String> clientImpMap = new HashMap<String,String> ();
    clientImpMap.put("1","High");
    clientImpMap.put("2","Low");
    return clientImpMap;
}
```

Now I want to populate this hashmap using Thymeleaf tags .How to do it?
Using core Spring-mvc tags I can do this

```
<td>Client Importance :</td>
    <td><form:select path="personBean.clientImpRef">
            <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
            <form:options items="${clientImpMap}"  />
        </form:select></td>
    <td><form:errors path="personBean.clientImpRef" cssClass="error" /></td>
</tr>
```

What is the equivalent of this in thymeleaf?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to do but does the following code fit the bill?

`<select th:field="*{personBean.clientImpRef}">
   <option th:each="entry : ${clientImpMap}" th:value="${entry.key}" th:text="${entry.value}">

   </option>
</select>`

If so let me know so I can add it as an answer. If not, you should post some more details to your question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following code corresponds to the jsp with spring tags that you have posted in your question.

```
<form action="your-controller-mapping" th:object="${personBean}">
   <select th:field="*{clientImpRef}">
      <option value="NONE">----Select----</option>
      <option th:each="entry : ${clientImpMap.entrySet()}" th:value="${entry.key}" th:text="${entry.value}">
        This will be replaced - is only used for natural templating
      </option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Comment: what is `clientImpRef` here?

Comment: @JavaTechnical It's the name of the field of Person bean

Comment: @geoand i am doing the same but after submit button it prints error can you help me with this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969634/how-to-get-the-posted-value-in-hashmap-using-spring-and-thymeleaf

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code & link

```
th:each="item : ${items}" th:text="${item.description}"
```

[Thymeleaf for each for select option & similar scenarios](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence)

```
<ul>
  <li th:each="item : ${items}" th:text="${item.description}">Item description here...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please check how to format answers on SO. You can use things such code highlight and the more you explain why this answers works, the better. Here is a link about how to format http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting