# How to get the posted value in Hashmap using spring and thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Good day,

I am trying to show the select field options by Hashmap and get the posted value back too.

I am using two classes one is for controller and the other for model.

```
public class MyForm {
   private int id;
   private Map<String, String> list;
   //getter setters
}

@Controller
public class MyController {

  @GetMapping("/create")
  public String showForm(MyForm myForm) {
    Map<String, String> list = new HashMap();
    list.put("US", "United States")
    list.put("UK", "United Kingdom")
    return "myview"
  }


  @PostMapping("/create")
  @ResponseBody
  public String showForm(MyForm myForm) {

    return "id: " + myform.getId() + " list: " + myform.getList();
  }

}
```

and here is the template.

```
<form th:action="@{/create}" th:object="${myForm}" method="POST">
 <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
 <p>
 Countries : 
 <select id="list" name="list">
  <option th:each="c : *{list}" th:value="${c.key}" th:text="${c.value}"></option>
 </select>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>            
</form>
```

when i open localho:8080/test its show me a text field and select filed with both options united states and united kingdom.

After typing 1 in id field and choosing united kingdom and then i press submit button it shows

```
1, null
```

please help me in this.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind.

I have done it by adding extra field.

```
List<String> country;
```

in MyForm model class and assigned name country to the select field in thymeleaf.

```
<select id="country" name="country">
<option th:each="c : *{list}" th:value="${c.key}" th:text="${c.value}"></option>
</select>
```